# Site is Provisioned but Content Type List is still empty

Tags: event-receivers, feature-activation, feature-stapling, provisioning

I have this feature that I am trying to run in order to configure a site, this feature among other things creates pages based on content types, etc. The problem I am facing is that every time i am trying to enable the feature from code the site content type collection is always empty. I have tried:

- Include feature in a custom site definition
- Feature stapling to a OOB site
- `WebProvisioned` event
- `WebProvisionProvider` provision method
- Tried a Poling thread to keep checking **ContentType** collection count every 500ms - this throws an exception after some runs - `SPException`

If I do: `web.ContentTypes.Count` it allays returns zero even when `web.Provisioned=true`.

If I enable my feature manually all the content types are there as expected.

How do I go about solving this problem? Any ideas?

Thanks